# Is $SO_2$ an amenable group?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, paradoxes, amenability

In S. Wagon's "The Banach-Tarski Paradox," amenable groups are defined on p. 12 as follows:

> [amenable] groups bear a left-invariant, finitely additive measure of total measure one that is defined on all subsets.

He defines $SO_2$ to be the group of rotations of the unit circle, which he has used to show that $S_1$, the unit circle, is $SO_2$-paradoxical (as an analogue to the usual non-measurable set defined in the interval $[0,1)$ ).  I am taking measure theory this term, but am not sure how to assign a measure to subsets of $SO_2$.  Thus, I am not really sure where to start in showing whether or not $SO_2$ is an amenable group.

When I look at the Wikipedia entry about amenable groups, I'm unable to make much more sense of the definition in the context of the material.

Is $SO_2$, the group of rotations of the unit circle, an amenable group?  If not, why (so that I may build an intuition for these objects)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For groups with a topology, like $SO_2$, one usually uses a slightly different definition. You will find it in Wikipedia.

Now, it is easy to see that a compact group is amenable, and $SO_2$ is compact.

If you insist on ignoring the topology of $SO_2$, though, you are still left with an abelian group. And all discrete abelian groups are amenable---but this is harder to see.

Comment: I'm curious: In what sense is it easier to see that compact groups are amenable than that discrete abelian groups are amenable?

Comment: @Theo: using the Wikipedia definition, you'd integrate with respect to the Haar measure.  For $SO_2$ that's the $SO_2$-invariant Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Ryan: of course, $SO_2$ is fine and very easy. However, amenability of abelian groups is obtained in a blow using Kakutani-Markov, while I can think of no way to prove amenability for compact groups that is similarly easy.

Comment: One might guess that the OP had in mind the "analogous" case of $SO_3$, whose non-amenability leads to the Banach-Tarski paradox.

Answer (score 6):

An amusing point is that the proof that there is a measure on the Abelian group of rotations is generally done using the Hahn-Banach Theorem, and that requires the Axiom of Choice. So this means that the proof that a Banach-Tarski Paradox does NOT exist in the plane requires the same Axiom of Choice that yields the paradox in 3-space.

But in fact one can eliminate (almost all of) AC from the proof that there is no BTP in the Euclidean plane.

Stan Wagon

Comment: Hahn-Banach doesn't require the full force of AC; you can prove it (so I am told) with the ultrafilter lemma.

Answer (score 4):

According to Terry Tao's notes [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional/) and [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/some-notes-on-amenability/) it is amenable.

Comment: +1 for the resources!  I had not come across this reference to B-T.