# Shellable and Graphs

Tags: algebraic-topology, graph-theory, terminology

Suppose we have a graph $G$ of order $n$. Also suppose that we form the [coloring complex](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1063771) $S(G)$ of $G$. What does it mean when we say that $S(G)$ is shellable?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of shellability of a simplicial complex, or something specific about the coloring complex?

Comment: @JIm Conant: The definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelling_%28topology%29) for the definition of a shelling of a simplicial complex.

Comment: I know this it's lame to just refer to Wikipedia, but their definition is correct and I can't really add much to it.

Comment: No need to feel bad, Jim, you're [answering](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19171/why-does-substitution-in-taylor-series-work/19176#19176) the [master](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/connection-between-graphs-and-the-eigenvectors-of-their-matrix-representation/19293#19293) of [doing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/is-so-2-an-amenable-group/25715#25715) [exactly](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18233/map-of-mathematical-logic/18234#18234) [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17625/proof-of-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbrn-d-p/17630#17630)!